# Como ejecutar un script php en python?

Tags: php, python, url

Necesito hacer que mi programa en python en un determinado momento corra un script php.
He visto alguas soluciones pero en esas es necesario tener el script.php.
Yo solo tengo la URL que permite ejecutar el script mediante un navegador.
¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

[file_get_content on python](https://gist.github.com/TwinProduction/8e8f928e5b0431e96b60d2caca40556d)

Esto un equivalente de una funcion de PHP a Python, lo que hace es ejecutar el script de una url y devuelve el contenido de este.

Checalo, espero y sea lo que buscas